# Need to create multiple excel .xls file using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xls

The following is a sample XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<MT_TEST_IN>
<RECORD>
  <NAME>AASHISH</NAME>
  <AGE>25</AGE>
  <Place>Chennai</Place>
</RECORD>
<RECORD>
  <NAME>Satheesh</NAME>
  <AGE>25</AGE>
  <Place>Coimbatore</Place>
</RECORD>
</MT_TEST_IN>
```

I need to 2 excel files based on the text of the NAME element.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">
<xsl:template match="/">
<Workbook>
  <Styles>
    <Style ss:ID="Default" ss:Name="Normal">
      <Alignment ss:Vertical="Bottom" />
      <Borders />
      <Font />
      <Interior />
      <NumberFormat />
      <Protection />
    </Style>
    <Style ss:ID="s21">
      <Font ss:Size="22" ss:Bold="1" />
    </Style>
    <Style ss:ID="s22">
      <Font ss:Size="14" ss:Bold="1" />
    </Style>
    <Style ss:ID="s23">
      <Font ss:Size="12" ss:Bold="1" />
    </Style>
    <Style ss:ID="s24">
      <Font ss:Size="10" ss:Bold="1" />
    </Style>
  </Styles>
  <Worksheet ss:Name="Page1">
    <Table>
      <xsl:call-template name="XMLToXSL" />
    </Table>
   </Worksheet>
  </Workbook>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template name="XMLToXSL">
  <Row ss:Index="1" >
  <Cell>
    <Data ss:Type="String">NAME</Data>
  </Cell>
   <xsl:for-each
  select="//RECORD">
    <Cell ss:Index="2">
      <Data ss:Type="String">
        <xsl:value-of select="NAME" />
      </Data>
    </Cell>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </Row>
   <Row ss:Index="2" >
  <Cell>
    <Data ss:Type="String">Place</Data>
  </Cell>
  <xsl:for-each
 select="//RECORD">
    <Cell ss:Index="2">
      <Data ss:Type="String">
        <xsl:value-of select="Place" />
      </Data>
    </Cell>
  </xsl:for-each>
</Row>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="DataList">
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I want 2 excel files based on the value of the "NAME" element. On the one excel file the details for the name "AASHISH" and on another excel file those for "Satheesh". Not a separate sheet. I need separate excel files.

Kindly help me with this issue.

Comment: Please add your used processor to your question via [edit] please. XSLT 1 can not do it natively. Only extensions or special processors with built-in extensions can do it. XSLT 2 solved this with tag `xsl:result-document`. Shortest hint: `<xsl:result-document href="{RECORD/NAME}">`

Comment: More specifically, if you are using XSLT 1.0 then the only way to produce two output files is either (a) use vendor-specific extensions, or (b) run two transformations, one for each output file (perhaps using the same stylesheet with different parameter values).

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code-outsourcing company. Show us your work. Show us that you have already invested (some) effort into making this work, rather than blindly asking others to solve your problem for you. The goal of StackOverflow is to learn. Not to outsource.